# Uniform distribution of p-values

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I have a question regarding the distribution of p-values.

http://varianceexplained.org/statistics/interpreting-pvalue-histogram/

In this article it says that under the null hypothesis the distribution of p-values is uniform.

I simulated 5 observations following a N(0,1) and performed a normality test. I did that 1000 times, and then I drew the histogram of the p-values. It looks very uniform.

Now I do the same thing, but instead of simulating 5 observations, I simulate 10,000.

Now the shape of the p-value distribution is clearly not uniform but most of the points are on the right. To me it makes sense as most p-values will be higher than my confidence interval, and I will conclude it’s very likely to be Gaussian.

But according to this article, the second case show there is something wrong whereas the fist one show it’s normal. To me intuitively it doesn’t make sense to have an uniform distribution. That would mean that the probably of having a p-value between 0 and 1 is the same, so what should I conclude?

Comment: If you sample repeatedly from the null you should get a uniform so I suspect there is something wrong with your simulation code.

Comment: But if the distribution is uniform it means that my pvalue has the same likelihood to fall in the rejection and the non rejection area ? So basically it means that if i do a single draw i can’t conclude whether i can reject or not as it could be a pvalue coming from everywhere between 0 and 1 as it’s uniform. I mean why not draw an uniform between 0 and 1 to conclude if i can reject any test instead of doing the test itself ?

Comment: Many tests are conservative, rather than exact, and will sometimes give a higher p-value than expected.  Which normality test did you use?

Comment: Kolmogorov-smirnov, but the things is that i have a uniform distribution when i have few observation and a non uniform when i have more observation using the same test.

Comment: This sounds like a restatement of your previous question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/399377/comparing-distribution-with-small-sample.  In what way do you intend it to differ?

Comment: Of course you can just sample from a uniform and reject if it is less than 0.05. You will end up with the specified $\alpha$ but if you calculate your $\beta$ you will see why we do not do it.

Comment: the beta? what do you mean ? i’m sorry but it’s not clear to me if i do a normality test (KS) with sample n-> oo then D -> 0 and pvalue -> 1 rather than being uniform. where am i wrong ?

Comment: Uniformity of the P-value holds when test statistics are exact and have continuous distributions. Some normality tests use discrete tests statistics and some use statistics that are not exact .(They give exact P-values below perhaps 20% to be useful for testing hypotheses, but give rough approximations for higher P-values, especially ones near 100%.) // In my brief simulation expt just now $(n = 1000$ from std normal, 10^5 iterations), Shapiro-Wilk P-values were not uniformly dist'd, esp. near 100%. Even P-values for samples of $n=5$ didn't look exactly uniform. // Try t-test for success.

Answer (score 2):

I expect that there is something wrong with your simulation(s).

Let's try this using R, first with a sample size (`n.samp`) of 5

```
set.seed <- 15
n.sim <- 1000
v.sim <- numeric(n.sim)
n.samp <- 5

for (i in 1:n.sim) {
  X <- rnorm(n.samp)
  ks <- ks.test(X, "pnorm")
  v.sim[i] <- ks$p.value
}

hist(v.sim)
```

[image: sample size is 5]

Now when we change `n.samp` to 10000, we obtain:

[image: sample size is 10000]

...as expected.

Comment: @PierreSiegelbaum does this answer your question ? If so, please consider marking it as the accepted answer, if not, perhaps I can help further ?